# install error of bsts package in R

Tags: r, gcc, centos

Installation of the R package [bsts](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bsts/index.html) on CentOS 6.3 fails with (truncated) error below. I already tried updating GCC to version 4.8.2 as suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/causalimpact/SEzQQOfhJiI/WVKrFWewkjUJ). Any other suggestions?

> - installing *source* package ‘Boom’ ...
>     ** package ‘Boom’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>     ** libs
>     g++ -m64 -std=c++0x -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I. -I../inst/include -IBmath -Imath/cephes -Icblas -DNO_BOOST_THREADS -DNO_BOOST_FILESYSTEM -DADD_ -DRLANGUAGE -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/BH/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -c Models/Bart/Bart.cpp -o Models/Bart/Bart.o
>     Models/Bart/Bart.cpp: In member function ‘void BOOM::Bart::VariableSummary::finalize(int,
>     BOOM::Bart::ContinuousCutpointStrategy)’:
>     Models/Bart/Bart.cpp:110:65: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
>                  if (number_of_unique_values < observed_values_.size()) {
>                                                                      ^
>     Models/Bart/Bart.cpp:117:65: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
>                  if (number_of_unique_values < observed_values_.size()) {
>                                                                      ^
>     Models/Bart/Bart.cpp:129:61: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
>              if (number_of_unique_values < observed_values_.size()) {
>                                                                  ^

Lots of this:

```
 Models/Bart/Bart.cpp:1393:50: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
      if (number_of_trees_to_remove >= trees_.size()) {
                                                   ^
 {standard input}: Assembler messages:
 {standard input}:71: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
 {standard input}:617: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
 {standard input}:664: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
 {standard input}:727: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
 {standard input}:790: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
 {standard input}:1171: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
 {standard input}:1180: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
 {standard input}:1231: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
 {standard input}:2704: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
 {standard input}:2796: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
 {standard input}:7412: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
 {standard input}:7504: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
 {standard input}:19481: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
 {standard input}:23959: Error: expecting string instruction after `rep'
 make: *** [Models/Bart/Bart.o] Error 1
 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Boom’
 * removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/Boom’
 ERROR: dependency ‘Boom’ is not available for package ‘BoomSpikeSlab’
 * removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/BoomSpikeSlab’
 ERROR: dependencies ‘BoomSpikeSlab’, ‘Boom’ are not available for package ‘bsts’
 * removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/bsts’

 The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpf9YQJJ/downloaded_packages’
 Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
 Making 'packages.html' ... done
 '/usr/lib64/R/bin/R' --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
   '/tmp/Rtmpf9YQJJ/devtoolsa12a5ce5a465/google-CausalImpact-9c9286f'  \
   --library='/usr/lib64/R/library' --install-tests 

 ERROR: dependency ‘bsts’ is not available for package ‘CausalImpact’
 * removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/CausalImpact’
 Error: Command failed (1)
 In addition: Warning messages:
 1: In utils::install.packages(deps, dependencies = NA, Ncpus = threads) :
   installation of package ‘Boom’ had non-zero exit status
 2: In utils::install.packages(deps, dependencies = NA, Ncpus = threads) :
   installation of package ‘BoomSpikeSlab’ had non-zero exit status
 3: In utils::install.packages(deps, dependencies = NA, Ncpus = threads) :
   installation of package ‘bsts’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Your problem seems to be with the Boom package.  Did you check that you are downloading the most recent version?

Comment: Yes - similar errors occur trying to load dependencies Boom and Boom SpikeSlab. I'm getting the most recent version from CRAN. Should I be looking elsewhere?

Comment: Hi, have you solved the issue with installing `Boom` ? If yes, may I ask how?

Comment: @Googme Sadly I haven't. I had no problems installing on Mac and Windows, so have just used those alternatives.

Comment: I ran into similar problems with 'Boom'. Any ideas how to solve it? This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858596/installing-package-on-r-need-c11-support-for-osx did not help.

Comment: thanks @Michal. it looks like you found a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36034316/r-package-boom-fails-to-install-on-ubuntu-linux)? if you put that in here, i could accept it as an answer here.

Comment: Indeed I did. Answer incoming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case installing new versions (4.9) of C++ and Fortran compilers helped (see [R package 'Boom' fails to install on Ubuntu linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36034316/r-package-boom-fails-to-install-on-ubuntu-linux/36034866#36034866), hat tip to Dirk Eddelbuettel). I had versions 4.8 earlier and they did not work.

I am not sure how to do that on CentOS, but I am sure it is possible to upgrade the compilers one way or another. The steps for Ubuntu (14.04) are:

1. Add `ubuntu-toolchain-r` PPA with `add-apt-repository`. I additionally used pinning (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) so that other packages are not automatically updated from that PPA.
2. Install packages `g++-4.9` and `gfortran-4.9`.
3. Set the environment variables `CXX=g++-4.9` and `CXX1X=g++-4.9` in either `~/.R/Makevars` or your `/etc/R/Makeconf`.
4. Install 'Boom'.

Comment: Missed that this was on Ubuntu -- doesn't help on CentOS. I did try a similar approach without success, even though I confirmed using gcc v4.8 and gfortran v4.8. I'm thinking there's something odd about my system. Will accept anyway as it may help others

Comment: I have updated the answer. I had 4.8 versions earlier and they did not work, so try 4.9. I am not sure how to that on CentOS unfortunately.

Comment: See here for some "partial" help how to upgrade the compilers on CentOS http://superuser.com/questions/834862/how-to-install-g-4-9-2-in-cent-os-6-5