# R package 'Boom' fails to install on Ubuntu linux

Tags: r, ubuntu

For some reason R package 'Boom' fails to install on my system (Ubuntu 14.04). R and all other packages are in their most recent versions (including 'BH'). As 'Boom' is on CRAN it should be expected that the package will install without any problems (e.g. [Installing package on R, need C++11 support for OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858596/installing-package-on-r-need-c11-support-for-osx)). However, I have no idea how to trace the cause: in what way my setup might differ from "the standard" so that the package does not install? Where to look?

Here is the offending part of the install log:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I../inst/include -IBmath -Imath/cephes -DNO_BOOST_THREADS -DNO_BOOST_FILESYSTEM -DADD_ -DRLANGUAGE  -I"/home/mbojan/R/library/3.2/BH/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c Models/PosteriorSamplers/DirichletPosteriorSampler.cpp -o Models/PosteriorSamplers/DirichletPosteriorSampler.o
Models/PosteriorSamplers/DirichletPosteriorSampler.cpp: In member function ‘void BOOM::DirichletPosteriorSampler::draw_impl(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BOOM::DirichletSampler::DirichletSamplerImpl> >&, const BOOM::Vector&)’:
Models/PosteriorSamplers/DirichletPosteriorSampler.cpp:90:65: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BOOM::DirichletSampler::DirichletSamplerImpl> >::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::shared_ptr<BOOM::DirichletSampler::DirichletSamplerImpl>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BOOM::DirichletSampler::DirichletSamplerImpl> > >)’
         other_implementations.erase(impl.begin() + which_sampler);
                                                                 ^
Models/PosteriorSamplers/DirichletPosteriorSampler.cpp:90:65: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/vector:69:0,
                 from ../inst/include/Models/DataTypes.hpp:24,
                 from ../inst/include/Models/ParamTypes.hpp:22,
                 from ../inst/include/Models/ModelTypes.hpp:22,
                 from ../inst/include/Models/DirichletModel.hpp:22,
                 from ../inst/include/Models/PosteriorSamplers/DirichletPosteriorSampler.hpp:23,
                 from Models/PosteriorSamplers/DirichletPosteriorSampler.cpp:18:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc:134:5: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _Tp = std::shared_ptr<BOOM::DirichletSampler::DirichletSamplerImpl>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<BOOM::DirichletSampler::DirichletSamplerImpl> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<BOOM::DirichletSampler::DirichletSamplerImpl>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BOOM::DirichletSampler::DirichletSamplerImpl> > >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = std::shared_ptr<BOOM::DirichletSampler::DirichletSamplerImpl>*]
     vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc:134:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::shared_ptr<BOOM::DirichletSampler::DirichletSamplerImpl>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BOOM::DirichletSampler::DirichletSamplerImpl> > >’ to ‘std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BOOM::DirichletSampler::DirichletSamplerImpl> >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<BOOM::DirichletSampler::DirichletSamplerImpl>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BOOM::DirichletSampler::DirichletSamplerImpl> > >}’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc:146:5: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _Tp = std::shared_ptr<BOOM::DirichletSampler::DirichletSamplerImpl>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<BOOM::DirichletSampler::DirichletSamplerImpl> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<BOOM::DirichletSampler::DirichletSamplerImpl>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BOOM::DirichletSampler::DirichletSamplerImpl> > >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = std::shared_ptr<BOOM::DirichletSampler::DirichletSamplerImpl>*]
     vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc:146:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
make: *** [Models/PosteriorSamplers/DirichletPosteriorSampler.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Boom’
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try a newer compiler: install `g++-4.9` and set

```
CXX=g++-4.9
CXX1X=g++-4.9
```

in either `~/.R/Makevars` or your `/etc/R/Makeconf`.  I just rebuilt Boom yesterday on a machine at work (though that was an Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10 upgrade which required a rebuild because of the switch to g++-5).

Comment: I installed `g++-4.9` from the `ubuntu-toolchain-r` PPA and set the envars as you suggested. The package almost installs but trips at linking (I think) with `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran`. Is there some other ubuntu package I am missing? Running `gfortran -v` says that it comes from gcc 4.8.5 (I think). Apologies for C++-ignorance!

Comment: Fortran != C++, but yes, you need that too.  See dozens of other questions on that here.   The same PPA may have the gfortran package you need.

Comment: OK, installed `g++-4.9` and `gfortran-4.9` from the above PPA and 'Boom' installs like a charm. Thanks!